# File not being created - Python - pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I'm currently learning python, i've written a program that calculates the cost to make a 3d print based on printer costs, overheads, profits etc.  I have the base program working correctly and looking to add a feature where a user can enter and save their own cost so it can be customised to each user.

I've tried using pickle to save/load a dictionary to store these values (not sure if that's the best approach?).  It worked initially but now i'm getting the issue that the pkl file is not being created if i run the code.  Sure i'm missing something simple but any help appreciated.

Heres the code i'm using

```
import pickle

printer_vars = {'cost':9999999999, 'life_expectancy':5, 'yearly_work_time':1200, 'bed_surface':16, 'belts':10, 'nozzles':11, 'hotend':49, 'power_per_hour':0.25, 'power_price':0.15}

# write python dict to a file
def save_defaults():
    printer_vars_stored = open('printer_vars.pkl','wb')
    pickle.dump(printer_vars, printer_vars_stored, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    printer_vars_stored.close()

# read python dict back from the file

def open_defaults():
    printer_vars_open = open('printer_vars.pkl','rb')
    printer_vars = pickle.load(printer_vars_open)
    printer_vars_open.close()
    return printer_vars
```

Comment: You have two functions, but there is no code showing that you actually call them.

Comment: The Python pickle format is quick and easy, but not very portable. Since your comments suggests you're only storing a dict, you are better off using a more portable format, such as JSON (which translates very easily to and from a Python dict).

Comment: Also, it's preferred to use with `with` statement when opening files. See the [relevant section in the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: You're not using absolute path, which means that the file will be generated wherever your current working directory is.   Do a file search on your OS and you should see.  To fix that, add the absolute path of your file instead of just putting the file name.

Comment: If `save_results` is being called either the file is being created or an error is raised. if `open_defaults` is being called, either the file does exist or an error is raised. You'll need to add code that calls these functions for us to comment further. It may be that you are not saving the return value from `open_defaults` back into the global `printer_vars`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, i think i've sorted it my call to the function wasn't correct as @tdelaney mentioned hence the file not being created.  I got mixed up as was calling the functions from a main script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to python too, but i think maybe JSON is a better format. 
Here's some code i wrote to handle saving and reading your dict to JSON files. 
I also added code to make sure that it saves and opens the .json files from the same directory that has the script file.

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, and I mostly wrote this as a challenge for myself :)

```
import pickle
import json
#I'm importing os, and sys to make sure that the file is saved in the same directory as the scriptfile.
#If you want to change this, look for the comment that says #PATH.
import os
import sys


#This function takes two arguments. One is the dict containing the 3D printer data.
#The other is a string to name the file. Note that i'm adding the file type '.json', so only provide the name, ex: 'test'
def save_printer_dict(inData,fileName):
    try:
        #PATH, change the code: sys.path[0] if you want a static filepath
        with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], fileName+'.json'),'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(inData, outfile)
        return True
    except:
        print("Dict received not in proper format")
        return False
#This function takes a fileName as a string, adds '.json' to it, opens the content and adds it to a dict that is returned.
def open_printer_dict(fileName):
    try:
        returnData = {}
        #PATH, change the code: sys.path[0] if you want a static filepath
        with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], fileName+'.json'),'r') as infile:
            returnData = json.load(infile)
        return returnData
    except:
        print("Can't find "+str(fileName)+".json")
        return None


#Here i'm just trying the functions to make sure they work.
printer_vars = {'cost':9999999999, 'life_expectancy':5, 'yearly_work_time':1200, 'bed_surface':16, 'belts':10, 'nozzles':11, 'hotend':49, 'power_per_hour':0.25, 'power_price':0.15}

if save_printer_dict(printer_vars,"test"):
    print("File saved")

#Calling this function with a valid filename returns a python dict.
print(open_printer_dict("test"))
```